# I have an error with the new ESLint config File, "eslint.config.js"

Tags: javascript, eslint

When I try to start linting on a file with the new configuration pattern, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\test> npx eslint index.js
(node:10036) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.41.0

C:\Users\test\eslint.config.js:1
export default [
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

This my code for now just to try to get it to work

`eslint.config.js`

```
export default [
    {
        rules: {
            semi: "error"
        }
    }
];
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",

  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint":"npx eslint index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.41.0"
  }
}
```

When I put "type: 'module'" inside my package.json, it will work of course. But I'm pretty sure this shouldn't be the solution. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: "But I'm pretty sure this shouldn't be the solution." — What makes you think that? It's the standard approach to writing ECMAScript module based NPM packages.

Comment: It's ok to specify  "type: 'module' cause now you are using modern module js, I do not know if it is possible to rename eslint file to eslint.config.mjs and that way I think you would not need to modify package.json

Comment: Renaming to `eslint.config.mjs` worked for me